# jquery Allow td doubleclick only when not contains input

Tags: jquery

I´ve following function for table editing:

```
$(function () {
$("td").dblclick(function () {
    var OriginalContent = $(this).text();

    $(this).addClass("cellEditing");
    $(this).html("<input type="text" value="&quot; + OriginalContent + &quot;" />");
    $(this).children().first().focus();

    $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            var newContent = $(this).val();
            $(this).parent().text(newContent);
            $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
        }
    });

$(this).children().first().blur(function(){
    $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent);
    $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
});
});
});
```

Which works like this: http://www.ssiddique.info/demo/editable-table-using-jquery

If I doubleclick the td an input is added to the cell, unfortunately the doubleclick is also fired if I double click inside the input which results in an empty input.

How can I prevent the secong double click? Or fire doubleclick only when td not contains an input?

Thanks,

t book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prevent the event propagating up the DOM tree. Something like the following:

```
$(this).find('input').dblclick(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ExA3j/2/)

Comment: thanks this brought me to this: $(this).children("input").length == 0 which is working.

Answer (score 1):

below checks if `td` is empty or not:

```
$("td").on('dblclick',function () {
    if( $(this).html()!='' ) alert('content')
    else alert('no content')
});
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WSRF3/

so in your example I would opt on only execute code if `td` has no content:

```
$("td").on('dblclick',function () {
    if( $(this).html()!='' ) return; // do nothing
    // continue your code here...
});
```